# Equivalence of two definitions of local maxima

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(\boldsymbol{x})$ be a multivariate function defined on a convex set $D\in \mathbb{R}^n$. A point $\boldsymbol{x}_0\in D$ is said to be a local maximum if there exists an $r>0$ such that $\forall \boldsymbol{x}\in D$, $|\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{x}_0|<r$ one has $f(\boldsymbol{x})\geq f(\boldsymbol{x}_0)$. A direction vector $\boldsymbol{y}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be feasible if $\exists \epsilon_0>0$ such that $\boldsymbol{x}_0+\epsilon \boldsymbol{y} \in D$, $\forall \epsilon \in (0,\epsilon_0)$. Suppose that for every feasible direction $\boldsymbol{y}$, there exists an $\epsilon_{\boldsymbol{y}} >0$ such that $\boldsymbol{x}_0+\epsilon \boldsymbol{y} \in D$ and $f(\boldsymbol{x}_0+\epsilon \boldsymbol{y})\geq f(\boldsymbol{x}_0)$, $\forall \epsilon \in (0,\epsilon_{\boldsymbol{y}})$. Does it imply that $\boldsymbol{x}_0$ is a local maximum? Is it possible to ensure that $\boldsymbol{x}_0$ is a local maximum by imposing any further restriction on $f$?

Comment: Uh, that's practically unreadable.  Can you get rid of every single backtick please (` character) and use \mathbf{} instead of ** ** everywhere?

Comment: \bf{x} will suffice for bold x.

Comment: I have edited the text. Please check now.